# "Precedente a qualcosa" o "precedente qualcosa"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

Qual è la forma corretta, con o senza la preposizione "a"? Ad esempio, cosa si dovrebbe dire:

- La settimana *precedente al* primo esame...

oppure

- La settimana *precedente il* primo esame... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sono ammesse entrambe le costruzioni (cf. per esempio il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/precedente/), che esemplifica «*la settimana p. alla partenza* (o, con costrutto diretto, *p. la partenza*)»).
Direi che, anche se non è la stessa cosa, sia una situazione simile a quella di altri aggettivi e sostantivi che originariamente erano participi presenti: in genere si dice “i componenti della commissione”, ma se uno “sente” il participio di “comporre” può dire “i componenti la commissione”.

Comment: Aggiungerei che il participio suona più formale dell'aggettivo («Il participio presente verbale, in italiano moderno, si riscontra solo nei registri formali e talvolta nella lingua letteraria. Compie normalmente la funzione sintattica di una relativa» ([1](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/participio_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/))). Il suo uso non si estende a tutti i verbi. Per esempio potrebbe suonare bizzarro dire "_Mario, amante la musica, andò al concerto_" anziché "_Mario, amante della musica, andò al concerto_": l'uso dell'aggettivo _amante_ come participio è molto raro.